# Does scanf() update constant variables?

Tags: c, constants, scanf

It seems that `scanf()` updates constant variables.

As far as I know, constant variables are supposed to have fixed values.

In the following code...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    const int testInteger = 0;

    printf("Before 'scanf', the value of the variable 'testInteger' is %d.\n", testInteger);

    // Does 'scanf' update constant variables?
    printf("Enter an integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &testInteger);

    printf("After 'scanf', the value of the variable 'testInteger' is %d.\n", testInteger);

    return 0;
}
```

...by entering the value of '50', it gives the following output:

```
Before 'scanf', the value of the variable 'testInteger' is 0.
Enter an integer: 50
After 'scanf', the value of the variable 'testInteger' is 50.
```

I would like to know why does `scanf()` update the value of the 'testInteger' constant variable.

Comment: Passing the address of a constant variable to `scanf()` causes undefined behavior. Anything can happen, including updating it.

Comment: MS Visual C does warn about this: 'scanf' : format string '%d' requires an argument of type 'int *', but variadic argument 1 has type 'const int *'

Comment: you don't use `const` because the constant variable not changing

Comment: TLDR answer:  you lied to the compiler when you passed a `const` variable to `scanf()`.

Comment: `const` basically means, "I promise not to try to modify this".  It does *not* mean, "Put this in read-only memory."  It does *not* mean, "I need a guarantee that if I accidentally break my promise, I'll reliably get an error message to alert me."  So you made a promise, and you broke that promise, and... you got away with it. C is like that sometimes. :-/

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's *supposed* to have constant value, but it doesn't magically *guarantee* it.

You took an address of this variable (of type `const int *`) which is nothing more than a number pointing to some memory. Then, by passing it to `scanf`, you violated the contract off const-ness (didn't you get any warnings? Do you compile with `-Wall`?): it was used as a regular `int*` pointer.

Answer (score 3):

C relies on the hardware to enforce the read-only-ness of `const` variables.  Most computer hardware can only enforce read-only-ness of large blocks of memory (known as "pages"), not individual `int`-sized variables.

You declared `testInteger` as a `const int`, but because it is otherwise an ordinary local variable -- it has "automatic storage duration", in the language of the C standard -- storage for it is allocated in a location (known as "the stack") whose large blocks have to remain writable for normal operation of the program, so the hardware cannot enforce its `const`ness.

If you change the declaration of `testInteger` to `static const int testInteger`, or if you declare it as a global, then it will be allocated in a special region of memory reserved for `const` variables (the "read-only data segment") whose blocks of memory *are* unwritable, and your program will crash inside the guts of `scanf` when it tries to write to `testInteger`.

It is almost always the Right Thing to declare `const` data objects as globals / with static storage duration *anyway*, so this hardware limitation is not a big deal in practice.  (Well, actually, it *is* a big deal, but for completely unrelated reasons.)

Answer (score 2):

Attempting to write a `const` object is undefined behavior (UB).  Might work, might not, might crash, might ...

```
const int testInteger = 0;
scanf("%d", &testInteger); // UB
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of issues here.

First, `const` *only* means "this thing may not be the target of an assignment operator", **not** "this thing must be stored in read-only memory."  The compiler is only *required* to issue a diagnostic if a `const`-qualified variable is the target of an assignment operator.

Secondly, the `%d` conversion specifier for `scanf` expects an argument of type `int *`, but we're passing an argument of type `const int *`.  However, this isn't a *constraint* violation the way assignment is, so no diagnostic is required.  Since we're passing the wrong type of argument to `scanf` for that conversion specifier, the behavior is *undefined*, which means that neither the compiler nor the run-time environment are required to handle the situation in any particular way.  In this case, your implementation updated the variable.  In an implementation where `testInteger` *was* stored in read-only memory, you might get a segfault or other runtime error, or the variable may simply not be updated.

Comment: Detail "... was stored in read-only memory, you'd get a segfault or similar runtime error." or maybe no reported error.

Comment: "First, `const` only means "this thing may not be the target of an assignment operator"" - this is misleading. "this thing may not be the target of an assignment operator" is one of the few things that are *enforced* about `const`, but it is not all that `const` means. Attempting to modify the value of a `const`-declared variable is undefined behavior, regardless of how the attempt is made.

Answer (score 1):

VC doesn't warn you, you have to add -Wall, I'm using either Dev C or Geany. It's not a compiler error though, it's just a not desirable output.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there are OS'es and compilers that can store const variables into read-only memory, but I also believe that most situations don't do that. It's more of a way to let a compiler know "I want you to warn me if I try to change this variable by mistake", but the compiler doesn't go so far as to check pointers to it, only direct references.